# Run SQL files against a remote machine using powershell

Tags: c#, sql, powershell, invoke-sqlcmd

What is the best way to execute the SQl scripts(ddl,sql) through powershell.

I'm using the below commandline to execute the scripts.

```
 Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile "C:\filepath\file1.ddl" -ServerInstance "10.166.23.28" -Database "DB1" -Username "sa" -Password "Pass01" -ConnectionTimeout 1000 | Out-File -FilePath "C:\scriptsout\TestSqlCmd.txt"
```

It is errored out by throwing the below error

```
    Invoke-Sqlcmd : Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or theserver is not responding.
```

When i execute a "select * from tablename" command it is working and writing the output to the Out-File

Comment: Increase the query timeout? Split the file into smaller batches?

Comment: @SalmanA I tried that, but still same issue

Comment: @tjdoubts Are you setting QueryTimeout or just  ConnectionTimeout? QueryTimeout is what you should increase. You can also set it to 0 for "indefinite".

Comment: There is `QueryTimeout` and `ConnectionTimeout` which do two different things

Comment: @BenOsborne and Chalieface Thanks , it worked

But in the Out-FIle i'm getting some table list, but what i want is the execution logs. Is there any way i can get the execution logs

Comment: Thanks,
I got it using the -verbose

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to execute it by using the below command

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile "C:\filepath\file1.ddl" -ServerInstance "10.166.23.28" -Database "DB1" -Username "sa" -Password "Pass01" -ConnectionTimeout 100 -QueryTimeout 0 -verbose *> "C:\filepath\File1.log"
```

By setting the QueryTimeout  to zero the compiler will wait indefinite until the script execution completed. Also setting the Verbose to * helps to maximize the logging and prevent logs from showing in the command prompt window.